# Form send and receive data between pages

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I try to send data from one form to another page via form method = "get". But that is not possible.

I use Visual Studio 2017 and Chrome and Edge and IE. I exactly followed the example of W3school but it really doesn't work.

The send page always keeps reappearing.

Does anyone know what's wrong with this example?

mysource 1

```
<%@ Page Title="About" Language="VB" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="TestSemd.aspx.vb" 
    Inherits="TESTMODULES.About" 
    EnableEventValidation="true" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent"   ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<html>
    <body>
          Window studio 2017,  Chrome  <br />
          page: TestSend.aspx<br />
          <Form id="F0" method="get"  action="~/TestRecieive.aspx" )
              <br /><br />
              First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"       value="Bill">   <br />
              Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Gates">  <br /><br />
           </form>
           <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
     </body>
 </html>
</asp:Content>
```

mysource 2

```
<%@ Page Title="About" Language="VB" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="Test REceive.aspx.vb" 
    Inherits="TESTMODULES.About" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent"    ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <html>
        <body>
            <form >
                <br /><br />
                Window studio 2017,  Chrome  <br />
                Page:    TestRecieive.aspx 
                <br /><br />
                Query string is: <%=Request.QueryString%>  
             </form> 
        </body>
     </html>
 </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

In TestSemd.aspx your action is `action="~/TestRecieive.aspx"` While your actual page name is `Test REceive.aspx`. Please rename your file and remove that space and try again.